# Bottom icons destroyed after use PDFViewerScaffold

Tags: flutter

I have Implemented a screen with app bar and two icons like following picture

[image: Before Add PDFViewerScaffold]

After I add the PDFViewerScaffold then all the icons and app bar not display only the pdf file displays

[image: After Added PDFViewerScaffold]

This my code

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Preview'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
  ),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        bottom: 10,
        left: 50,
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.description),
          iconSize: 30,
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () {}),
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 10,
        right: 50,
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.share),
          iconSize: 30,
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () {}),
      ),
      Positioned(
        child: PDFViewerScaffold(path:widget.pdfPath))
    ],
  ),
);
```

How can I display all the icons, appbar and pdf document in one screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_full_pdf_viewer), which uses `PDFViewerScaffold` to view the pdf.

When we go inside this class we find that it calls a method to view the pdf in fullscreen and add its own AppBar. You can't change that behavior, the only solution is to use another plugin.

This is [another plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_viewer_plugin) that can view pdf file inside your scaffold.

Comment: I am sorry for that, it works for me when I use hot reload but when the app restarts it is not working. I am searching for another solution.

Comment: when we add PDFViewerscafflod to our app hot reload isn't work we should have to restart the app

Comment: This plugin uses `PDFViewerScaffold` to view the pdf, when we go inside this class we find that it calls a method to view the pdf in fullscreen and add its own `AppBar`.
You can't change that behavior, the only solution is to use another plugin.
Check this plugin if it can help you: https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_viewer_plugin and comment back to edit my answer.

Comment: You're welcome, you means the other plugin has worked right?

Comment: yeah it worked can you update the answer so then I can upvote it